# How Does The Length Method Work In Modern Languages

Tags: arrays, string, list

Getting the length of an `iterator`, `list`, `array`, or `string` in most modern languages is quite a trivial thing. This usually involves running a `len()` method like in Python, or a `.length` property in JavaScript.

My question is, how is this length generally calculated? Is it iterated through every time you call the method, or is there a reference to the length somewhere in memory as the `list` or `string` may change in size? If the latter, where would this be stored? Is it just abstracted away by the compiler? Does this vary per language?

There are also instances of using `LINQ` in .net and the `count()` method, this one seems like it may use an iterative approach, so my curiosity stands.

Comment: Regarding Count(), the runtime would check if the underlying source implements ICollection<T> and if so, use the O(1) Count, so it's not always "oh count would be O(n)"

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the underlying data structure. For some, len is easy to find, for some it isn’t. For an iterator for example, in the general case you’d have to iterate through it and count the iterations - in special cases, like an iterator iterating through all array elements for a start to an end it’s trivial.

Imagine I create an iterator that iterates through all elements of an integer array whose values are prime numbers. How would you do this?